Forward traffic from docker to host
I have a docker acting as VPN server in a host. Then, the traffic passes trhough the eth0 of the host from a VPN client, then encrypted traffic, and finally arrives to the tun0 in the docker. What I want is to forward the dencrypted traffic to the host again. How could I do it?
Traffic flow:

VPN client
--encrypt(traffic)--eth0(host)--encrypt(traffic)--tun0(docker)--traffic--interface(host)


Enable IP forwarding (sysctl) in the server container, and set up source NAT (also in the container) for the VPN subnet, just like when the server isn't in a container.

I have already done the IP forwarding and I configured the rule for the NAT related to VPN subnet with this rule:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.255.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
being the 192.168.255.0 the network for the VPN but it doesn't work.

First of all, is the VPN connection itself working fine? (As in, can you reach the "server" itself, in this case the container, with its VPN IP address, e.g. 192.168.255.1?) Second, define "doesn't work" -- are the clients just not using the tunnel for e.g. "Internet" traffics, or, do they lose connectivity to the "Internet" once connected to the VPN server? Third, have you check with ways such as ping 8.8.8.8 which doesn't involve DNS resolution first? Fourth, what, like which IP address, is advertised to / configured on the clients as the DNS server?

FWIW, just in case something went wrong on the docker host, double check that the container itself has Internet connectivity (by e.g. using docker exec to get a shell and ping something from there). Also, although it's pretty unlikely the container itself would have firewall rules / chain policy that forbid the IP forwarding you desire, you may double check it with iptables-save and nft list ruleset as well.

The VPN is working fine, the traffic is reaching the server in the docker. For example, an ICMP from the VPN client  passes trhough the interface of the host encrypted and reaches the tun0 in the docker already decrypted at this moment.
